# What version of HDFS is compatible with HBase stable?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase

[HBase stable](http://apache.cs.utah.edu/hbase/stable/) is currently hbase-0.90.4, what version(s) of HDFS is it compatible with?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is hadoop-**0.20.205.0** but you also need to [replace jar files in ./lib/ of HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#trouble.versions.205) with the ones of your working HDFS installation.

For me it was:

```
rm /opt/hbase-0.90.4/lib/hadoop-core-0.20-append-r1056497.jar
cp /opt/hadoop-0.20.205.0/hadoop-core-0.20.205.0.jar /opt/hbase-0.90.4/lib/
cp /opt/hadoop-0.20.205.0/commons-configuration-1.6.jar /opt/hbase-0.90.4/lib/
```

In addition, you should to add the following to your HDFS and HBase configuration on all the nodes:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.support.append</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```